# how to use flink count window

Tags: java, apache-flink

when i use countwindow before windowfunction, after running the code i got the error like `State migration is currently not supported`, detail msg is

```java
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: org.apache.flink.util.StateMigrationException: State migration is currently not supported.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.create(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.InternalTimeServiceManager.createTimerPriorityQueue(InternalTimeServiceManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.InternalTimeServiceManager.registerOrGetTimerService(InternalTimeServiceManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.InternalTimeServiceManager.getInternalTimerService(InternalTimeServiceManager.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.getInternalTimerService(AbstractStreamOperator.java:741)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator.open(WindowOperator.java:225)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.EvictingWindowOperator.open(EvictingWindowOperator.java:430)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:424)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.StateMigrationException: State migration is currently not supported.
    at org.apache.flink.util.StateMigrationException.notSupported(StateMigrationException.java:42)
    ... 11 more
```

my generator code is

```java
SingleOutputStreamOperator singleOutputStream = iotDataSource.flatMap(new String2MetricFlatMapFunctionWithOutTimeAlignment())
    .filter(new WaterMarkFilterFunction(Time.seconds(WATERMARK_SIZE)))
    .filter(new DataCleanFilterFunction())
    .map(new RelateParkMapFunction())
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new CommonBoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor(Time.seconds(MAX_OUT_OF_ORDERNESS)))
    .keyBy((KeySelector<Metric, String>) metric -> metric.getPark())
    .countWindow(10,1)
    .apply(new RealTimeAlarmWindowApplyFunction(CACHE_SIZE))
    .map(new ResultMapFunction())
    .disableChaining();
```

maybe something wrong in `RealTimeAlarmWindowApplyFunction`,

```java
public class RealTimeAlarmWindowApplyFunction extends RichWindowFunction<Metric, ResultAction, String, GlobalWindow> {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RealTimeAlarmWindowApplyFunction.class);

    private int cacheDataSize;

    public RealTimeAlarmWindowApplyFunction(int cacheDataSize) {
        this.cacheDataSize = cacheDataSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(String key, GlobalWindow window, Iterable<Metric> input, Collector<ResultAction> out) throws Exception {
        //...
        // process code with no error 
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this question is fixed by cancled savepoit option when running flink job:

`$FLINK_HOME/bin/flink run -ynm jobname -yjm 1024 -ytm 4096 -yn 1 -ys 4 -qu root.users.root -flink_job_jar /root/flink_jar/test/flinkJobTest.jar -args 16`

ps: i run this job allways with savepoit option like this

`$FLINK_HOME/bin/flink run -ynm jobname -yjm 1024 -ytm 4096 -yn 1 -ys 4 -qu root.users.root -flink_job_jar /root/flink_jar/test/flinkJobTest.jar  -savepoint_prefix hdfs://nameservice1/flink-checkpoint  -args 16`

but after i change window type, savepoint is not allowed to restore

Comment: Yes, the savepoint contained state related to the previous version of the app, which used time windows. This state could not be restored, so the app failed to launch. There is an option (-allowNonRestoredState) that can be used in these situations, if you have other state that you do want restored.